# $D^2 \cup \{pt\} = S^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I think if I can ignore the metric, then $D^2$ only differs $S^2$ by a point, namely, the infinity. But I am wondering that if it is true that $D^2 \cup \{pt\} = S^2$?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to describe the topology on $D^2 \cup \{ \text{pt} \}$. More precisely, it is true that the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ is the [one-point compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension#The_one-point_compactification) of the open disk $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: Thank you Seirios for your answer. I am not sure about the topology on $D^2 \cup \{pt\}$ - perhaps point-topology? What the topologies could be...?

Comment: Usually, the topology is defined as $\mathcal{T} \cup \mathcal{T}_{\infty}$ where $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology on $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathcal{T}_{\infty}$ is the topology generated by the sets of the form $(\mathbb{D} \backslash K) \cup \{ \text{pt} \}$ where $K \subset \mathbb{D}$ is compact for $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you Seirios.